# Javascript - Get access to 'super' keyword via prototype

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I want to override a class method via the prototype property, but I'm not able to access the 'super' keyword.

```
class A {
    foo(){
        console.log('foo-foo');
    }
}

class B extends A {}

B.prototype.foo = function(){ super.foo() }
// Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here

// what I want:
const b = new B();
b.foo(); // foo-foo
```

The motivation here is to import the new b.foo from a separate file, as it is very long, but still be able to access A's method foo.

Comment: just comment out `//B.prototype.foo = function(){ super.foo() }`, it inherits from `A`...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use super outside of a class. Sorry, that's just how the language is. You could replace super with `Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype)`. But I'd think hard about splitting a class across several files in the first place.